# Returning before block in GMSMapViewDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, codeblocks, gmsmapview

I'm trying to update the UI inside the block, but the problem is that the method is returning before the block. How can I fix that? I want to return the object with all its properties updated.

I tried to get main_queue when updating UI but that didn't work.

thank you!!

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    // 1
    let index:Int! = Int(marker.accessibilityLabel!)
    // 2
    let customInfoWindow = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomInfoWindow
    customInfoWindow.userName.text = "hahah"

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").child(self.postsArray[index].userID).child("userInfo").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let username = snapshot.value!["name"] as! String
        customInfoWindow.userName.text = username



        // ...
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return customInfoWindow
}
```

Comment: How do to get the main thread? Please update your code.

Comment: that doesn't work because its returning the customInfoWindow object before the completion handler in the block.